# Getting value from function and adding outside of for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, return, return-value

I have the following:

```
public function go(){
            for($x=0;$x<=31;$x++) {
                $this->get_answerrules($x);
                $DoneTime+=$DoneTime;
            }
            echo $gmdate("i:s", $DoneTime);;
        }
```

and

```
public function get_answerrules($x){
 ...
 ...
 ... 
        if($response = $this->request($data)){
            $obj = json_decode($response,true); 
                foreach($obj as $file) {
                        $Time += $file['batch_dura'];
                }
                $DoneTime = $Time;
                return $DoneTime;
       }else{}  
}
```

How do I get the value from the 31 for loop cycles and add them together?

Right now my results are coming up blank.

Comment: Because you don't know about variables' scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the results of your method call:

```
public function go(){
    for($x=0;$x<=31;$x++) {
        $this->get_answerrules($x);
        $DoneTime+=$DoneTime;
    }
    // The below won't work as `$gmdate` is not in the scope of the method.
    echo $gmdate("i:s", $DoneTime);;
}
```

Should probably be something like:

```
public function go() {
    // Initialize the variable
    $DoneTime = 0;
    for($x = 0; $x <= 31; $x++) {
        $DoneTime += $this->get_answerrules($x);
    }
    echo $gmdate("i:s", $DoneTime);
}
```